# Can I use a constraint in solving systems of equations resulting from Lagrangians?

Tags: lagrange-multiplier, constraints

Say that this is a function to minimize:
$$F(x,y) = x^4+\frac 1 3 x^3 + \frac 1 2 x^2 - x + y^3$$
subject to the following constraints:
$$x^2+x-1=0$$
$$y \geq 5$$
I can introduce Lagrangian multipliers:
$$L(x,y,\alpha,\beta) = x^4+\frac 1 3 x^3 + \frac 1 2 x^2 - x + y^3 + \alpha(x^2+x-1)+\beta(y-5)$$
Then, one of the steps is going to be to set $\frac{\partial L}{\partial x} = 0$, i.e.:
$$4x^3+x^2+x-1+\alpha(2x+1)=0$$
Since $x^2+x-1=0$ is a constraint, may I replace $x^2+x-1$ in $\frac{\partial L}{\partial x}$ with $0$ to get:
$$4x^3+\alpha(2x+1)=0$$
and then proceed with solving the system?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes of course we can, indeed the constraint equation is a part of the system to be solved and thus the substitution in the others equations is allowed.